# Unable to push value onto Object Array?

Tags: javascript

So I have some code im working through on FreeCodeCamp:
https://jsfiddle.net/matt40413/m8wh7sxz/

Everything is working great until I try to push a value onto a new array (that doesn't exist yet) I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: collectionCopy[id].tracks.push is not a function`.

```
  if(prop == "tracks")
  {
    collectionCopy[id]["tracks"].push(value);
  }
```

This is where it's failing. But the funny thing is, if I MANUALLY put everything in such as: `collectionCopy[5439]["tracks"].push("Whatever")` works just fine!

So what's going on here? Im essentially doing the same thing? but just using the parameters instead (Which btw my other functions do work, so im a bit confused).

Comment: `collectionCopy[id]["tracks"]` presumably is not an array.

Comment: Might want to make sure `id` is actually equal to 5439

Comment: I have a feeling those that are downvoting me....aren't actually reading or looking at the jsfiddle.

Comment: @msmith1114 your code should be posted **here**. A fiddle is fine, but external links are frowned upon because we can't always rely on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(prop == "tracks")
  {
    if(!Array.isArray(collectionCopy[id]["tracks"]){
      collectionCopy[id]["tracks"] = [];
    }
    collectionCopy[id]["tracks"].push(value);
  }
```

create an array if it is not an array first

Comment: This worked perfectly! I guess I assumed the other "if" function would have created the array first.

Comment: @msmith1114 perhaps it can be usefull to check `collectionCopy[id].hasOwnProperty("tracks")` too.

Comment: Array.isArray is supported by modern browsers. For older browsers, you will need a Polyfill.

Comment: @alpeshpandya in older browsers you can try to check for undefined and/or null too

Comment: But that will not be accurate. The variable may contain other value type than Array in which case it will not be undefined, null or an Array. You will need a Polyfill or an anonymous function which can be used everywhere for such condition.

Answer (score 1):

Three comments about the code:

1. You are using the *if-else* statements as separated cases, that is not true! In order to separate each case, you should use *else if* statement
2. The problem in the code is that your first case was

   if(!collectionCopy[id][[prop]])

That is saying: if the key *[prop]* doesn't exists in *collectionCopy[id]*, then ...

Since *[prop]* is an array and not a number neither a string, the expression was always true. Therefore, it was executing *collectionCopy[id][prop] = value*.

Note: the keys are always string or numbers.

3. The rest of the code was correct and actually cool.

This is the corrected snippet.

```
// Setup
var collection = {
    "2548": {
      "album": "Slippery When Wet",
      "artist": "Bon Jovi",
      "tracks": [ 
        "Let It Rock", 
        "You Give Love a Bad Name" 
      ]
    },
    "2468": {
      "album": "1999",
      "artist": "Prince",
      "tracks": [ 
        "1999", 
        "Little Red Corvette" 
      ]
    },
    "1245": {
      "artist": "Robert Palmer",
      "tracks": [ ]
    },
    "5439": {
      "album": "ABBA Gold"
    }
};
// Keep a copy of the collection for tests
var collectionCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(collection));

// Only change code below this line
function updateRecords(id, prop, value) {

  if(!collectionCopy[id][prop])
  {
  collectionCopy[id][prop] = value;
  }
  else if(value == "")
  {
  console.log("DELETED");
    delete collectionCopy[id][prop.push]
  }
  else if(prop == "tracks")
  {
    collectionCopy[id]["tracks"].push(value);
  }
    console.log(collectionCopy);





  return collection;
}

// Alter values below to test your code
updateRecords(5439, "tracks", "Take a Chance on Me");
```

Working example https://jsfiddle.net/m8wh7sxz/2/

Comment: I didn't even notice I had double-bracketed my prop in the first if statement, oops! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change this part:

`collectionCopy[id]["tracks"].push(value);`

To:

`collectionCopy[id]["tracks"] = value;`

Because `collectionCopy[id]["tracks"]`is not initialized yet, there for you can't call `push()` function

Answer (score 0):

You simply initialized your object incorrectly, doing this will fix it:

```
updateRecords(5439, "tracks", ["Take a Chance on Me"]);
```

Now your push will append to this array! Before you were trying to run *`.push()`* on a string!

#### Edit:

If you need to dynamically construct the array when updating, you can do:

```
if (prop == "tracks") {
  console.log(collectionCopy[id]["tracks"])
  if (!(collectionCopy[id]["tracks"] instanceof Array)) {
    collectionCopy[id]["tracks"] = [value]
  } else collectionCopy[id]["tracks"].push(value)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately were not allowed to change what is "passed" into the function.

Comment: Do you still want to keep track of all things inserted to the same id? If so, I made the edit!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have "tracks" in "5439" object.

You should add it if you want to access it as array.

```
"5439": {
  "album": "ABBA Gold",
  "tracks":[]
}
```

EDIT:

This should work for you then.

```
else if(prop == "tracks")
{
   if(!("tracks" in collectionCopy[id]) ||  !(collectionCopy[id]
     ["tracks"].constructor === Array)){
       collectionCopy[id]["tracks"]=[];
   }
   collectionCopy[id]["tracks"].push(value);      

}
```

Comment: I know, however this is a programming quiz through free-code-camp and we need to be able to handle if the array doesn't exist

Answer (score -1):

You can't push onto an array property if it hasn't been initialized yet. You can use the following trick:

```
if(prop == "tracks")
{
  (collectionCopy[id]["tracks"] = collectionCopy[id]["tracks"] || []).push(value);
}
```

If the array is initilized, then `collectionCopy[id]["tracks"] || []` evaluates to `collectionCopy[id]["tracks"] || []`, otherwise it will evaluate to `[]` thus a new property of `array` type being initialized.